# Generate a list of App Pool Virtual Path authentication settings using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, authentication, iis

I have been looking at all the PowerShell commands like Select-WebConfiguration, Get-WmiObject, Get-IISAppPool to generate a list of the enabled App Pool authentication settings for all the app pools on my servers. We have like 10 servers and a dozen+ app pools on each and want to find a quick way to check settings. Checked a lot on the web and haven't been able to find a command to generate a nice neat listing.

Comment: "Authentication" has nothing to do with "application pool". You misunderstood the basic concepts.

Comment: Sorry I should have worded that better. It is a virtual path associated with an app pool. I am looking to get the authentication settings for the ones associated with the app pools.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the iis application pool identity then you could try the below command:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools\ | 
Select-Object name, @{e={$_.processModel.username};l="username"}, <#@{e={$_.processModel.password};l="password"}, #> @{e={$_.processModel.identityType};l="identityType"} |
format-table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to piece this together below and it seemed to work. Once last thing I am trying to figure out is how to use this same command to query remote servers

Get-WebConfiguration  system.webServer/security/authentication/*  -Recurse | where {$_.enabled -eq $true} | Sort-Object location,itemxpath | Select location,itemxpath,enabled | format-table -AutoSize

Answer (score 0):

I found out that to run this command on another machine you use the command enter-pssession and the server name. It does not provide any switches that allow you to run them on another server.